# Merging arrays with objects - update duplicates based on keys and add unique

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays with objects in them.
I am looking to merge the arrays and either update or add objects to the merged arrays.

If the objects are being updated I need one of the values to be incremented with the matched object.

Here is an example of the data and the result I need.

**Array 1:**

```
[
    {
        "user": "user1",
        "time": 8600
    },
    {
        "user": "user2",
        "time": 8600
    }
]
```

**Array 2:**

```
[
    {
        "user": "user1",
        "time": 5400
    },
    {
        "user": "user3",
        "time": 5400
    }
]
```

**Need those 2 arrays to turn into:**

```
[
    {
        "user": "user1",
        "time": 14000
    },
    {
        "user": "user2",
        "time": 8600
    },
    {
        "user": "user 3",
        "time": 5400
    }
]
```

You will see that `user 1` has been updated. The time value for `user 1` has been added together (8600 + 5400)
And `user 3` has been added as a new object to the array.

I have tried looping through one array and testing for each object, but wasn't successful in getting the results I needed.
I have looked at things like `array_merge_recursive` but I don't think that will do what I need.

Here is the code I have tried

```
$newArray = array();

foreach ($array1 as $user) {
    $array1User = $user->user;
    $array1Time = $user->time;

    foreach ($array2 as $user2) {
        $array2User = $user2->user;
        $array2Time = $user2->time;

        // If the user already exists
        if ($array1User == $key => $array2User) {
            // Update item
            $newArray[$key]->time = $array1Time + $array2Time;
        }
        else {
            // Add item
            $newObj = new stdClass();
            $newObj->user = $newAttendeeEmail;
            $newObj->time = $newAttendeeTime;

            // Add new attendee to event details
            $newArray[] = $newObj;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you tried, you might be very close.

Comment: As with most questions on SO. If you post the code you wrote in your attempt you are more likely to get assistance from the community. If you dont it just looks like you cannot be bothered to try and do it yourself and the question gets closed as Too Broad, as we are very happy to help each other, but we dont write code for each other from what basically amounts to a specification

Comment: I have added the code I have tried.

Comment: SHoudl we assume you have already done the conversion from JSON to PHP Array and that `$array1` and `$array2` are the result of that?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Correct, these are put together in PHP.

Comment: _Just a small point_ That JSON is not valid! Strings have to be in double quotes, is that just a typo when you created the question or is that the raw JSON String that you are actually dealing with

Comment: @RiggsFolly for sure, was me just inputting. Have updated.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you and the result will be `$array1` containing all the users and the accumulated times.

> I had to change the JSON Strings for the 2 arrays to make them valid JSON, so beware if your JSON String actually contains single quoted variable names and values as that is not valid JSON

```
<?php 

$json1 = '[
    {
        "user": "user1",
        "time": 8600
    },
    {
        "user": "user2",
        "time": 8600
    }
]';
$json2 = '[
    {
        "user": "user1",
        "time": 5400
    },
    {
        "user": "user3",
        "time": 5400
    }
]';

$array1 = json_decode($json1);
$array2 = json_decode($json2);

foreach ($array1 as $one) {
    $found = false;
    foreach ($array2 as $two ) {
        // does array 2 contain a user not in array1
        if ( $one->user == $two->user) {
            $one->time += $two->time;
            $found = true;
            break;   
        }
    }   
    // cannot of found this user in $two so add it to $one
    if ( ! $found ) {
        $array1[] = $two;
    }
}

print_r($array1);
```

RESULTS

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user] => user1
            [time] => 14000
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user] => user2
            [time] => 8600
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user] => user3
            [time] => 5400
        )

)
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. I have noticed that if `$json2` had an 3 objects within it `$json2 = '[
    {
        "user": "user1",
        "time": 5400
    },
    {
        "user": "user2",
        "time": 5400
    },
    {
        "user": "user3",
        "time": 5400
    }
]';` it would update the duplicate objects, but not add the new user to array1

Comment: Ahh let me look at that